# UWP c# Анимация SpilitView

Tags: c#, uwp

Почему панель в SpilitView в режиме inline выезжает без анимации? И можно ли это как нибудь исправить?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt590204.aspx Можно развернуть шаблон ListView, и делать внутри что угодно, в том числе указать анимацию выплывания панели. Нужно найти только нужный State и поправить шаблон как вам угодно

Comment: А в каком месте этого длинного описания шаблона с МСДН прописана анимация выезда панельки?..

Answer (score 1):

Как уже указали выше надо менять шаблон. Но прежде чем туда лезть, крайне рекомендую почитать, что там вообще надо менять. Вот тут описана работа с анимацией https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819808 
В принципе всё просто, после прочтения будет понятно что и где надо менять в шаблоне.